# Convert array structure for ul() codeigniter helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask how to convert an array like below:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Home',
        'link_to' => 'home.php',
        'parent' => 0,
        'level' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'About',
        'link_to' => 'about.php',
        'parent' => 0,
        'level' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'About Me',
        'link_to' => 'about-me.php',
        'parent' => 2,
        'level' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'About Us',
        'link_to' => 'about-us.php',
        'parent' => 2,
        'level' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Contact Us',
        'link_to' => 'contact-us.php',
        'parent' => 4,
        'level' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Blog',
        'link_to' => 'blog.php',
        'parent' => 0,
        'level' => 1
    ),
);
```

into this one:

```
$result = array(
    'Home',
    'About' => array(
        'About Me',
        'About Us' => array(
            'Contact Us'
        )
    ),
    'Blog'
);
```

there are element 'parent' id which can tell the parent array ( 0 = root) and there are also element 'level'.

I need that kind of array so I can create list using `ul()` function from codeigniter helper.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, have you tried it yourself?

Comment: You should spell out the whole Array because the relationship between some of the new elements is less then obvious. It seems like you want to flip some values with keys and you could use `array_flip` for that http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to do something similar to create a tree from data rows.

So, you have to work with references, it is easier than others ways.

The next code arrive to something similar of what you want (i think it's better structure if you makes changes later)

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Home',
            'link_to' => 'home.php',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'About',
            'link_to' => 'about.php',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'About Me',
            'link_to' => 'about-me.php',
            'parent' => 2,
            'level' => 2
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'About Us',
            'link_to' => 'about-us.php',
            'parent' => 2,
            'level' => 2
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Contact Us',
            'link_to' => 'contact-us.php',
            'parent' => 4,
            'level' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 6,
            'name' => 'Blog',
            'link_to' => 'blog.php',
            'parent' => 0,
            'level' => 1
        ),
    );


    $refs = array();

    foreach($arr as &$item) {
        $item['children'] = array();
        $refs[$item['id']] = $item;
    }

    unset($item); // To delete the reference

    // We define a ROOT that is the top of each elements
    $refs[0] = array(
        'id' => 0,
        'children' => array()
    );

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        if($item['id'] > 0) {
            $refs[$item['parent']]['children'][] = &$refs[$item['id']];
        }
    }

    $result = $refs[0];

    unset($refs); // To delete references

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And thanks for pointing the usage of references in foreach loop.